# ¿Es "portarse" (a secas) lo mismo que "portarse bien"?

Tags: gramática, expresiones, expresiones-fijas

Estaba hablando sobre un bebé y me dijeron "hoy se ha portado", queriendo decir que "hoy se ha portado *bien*".

El DRAE (con nueva web, por cierto) lo refleja:

> **[portar](http://dle.rae.es/?w=portar&o=h)**
>
> Del lat. portāre.
>
> (...)
>
> 5. prnl. coloq. Tener una actuación especialmente buena en una determinada situación.

Esta omisión del "bien" dando por descontado que "portarse" a secas tiene una connotación positiva me llevó a pensar: ¿qué nombre recibe este comportamiento lingüístico de la palabra? ¿qué es en sí el hecho de que un verbo sin un calificativo tenga una connotación determinada?

Observo que no ocurre en otros verbos: con "estar", por ejemplo, si alguien te pregunta cómo estás, contestar "estoy" no tiene una connotación positiva per se (lo mismo es un poco negativa y todo).

Comment: En Chile no se entendería "portarse" a secas. En cambio sí funciona con "comportarse". Uno puede amonestar a un hijo o un alumno diciéndole _¡Compórtese!_, que significa "compórtese bien".

Comment: Así como dice @Rodrigo cuando me enseñaron la lengua en EE. UU. Pero rápido aprendí la forma simple de *portarse*. Creo que el término más obvio sería polisemia, pero no soy perito en la lingüística general para saber si hay un término incluso más específico.

Answer (score 4):

Sí, en cuanto lo leí me di cuenta que está mal utilizado, sí bien la rae lo respalda, así mismo lo aclara:

> 5. prnl. **coloq.** Tener una actuación especialmente buena en una determinada situación.

En negrita remarqué la abreviatura de la palabra "coloq", que en realidad significa coloquial.

[Coloquial en la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=coloquial&m=form&o=h)

---

Dicho de otra forma, se usa vulgarmente, pero no es del todo correcto. Lo mismo ocurre con **prnl.**

> 5. **prnl.** coloq. Tener una actuación especialmente buena en una determinada situación.

Alude a que debe conjugarse, o ponerse en contexto.

---

Su uso correcto sería:

> *"Se ha portado bien".*

---

Con respecto a "estar", no me seria raro que ocurra lo mismo, dependiendo de la región en que estés, pero sí que suena forzada una situación en la que te respondan.

> *"¿Qué quieres que te diga? estoy..."*

Queriendo decir que no se está ni bien ni mal. Es una respuesta poco clara.

Answer (score 1):

Yo soy español y solo te puedo hablar del español usado en mi país.

El verbo "portarse", sin complemento directo, es bastante usado, aunque como bien habéis indicado, pertenece al registro coloquial. Por eso, no se entiende en todos los países hispanohablantes, como demuestra el comentario de Rodrigo. En cambio, la expresión "portarse bien" es más precisa y elaborada. Es muy usada y no es coloquial, aunque tampoco pertenece al registro literario.

Answer (score 1):

En México **portarse**  (a secas) no implica portarse bien. En este sentido se usa, en cambio, **comportarse** (a secas) que sí lleva (en México) implícito el sentido de bueno.

Comment: Interesante, Krauss. Entonces, la frase que menciono en la pregunta _hoy se ha portado_ no tendría suficiente información como para que se entendiera en México, ¿verdad?

Comment: Correcto, en México no se sabría si se ha portado bien o mal.